# Reset Expo Permissions

Tags: ios, push-notification, expo

Is there's a way to Reset the Permissions that I’ve already chosen?

I have denied the permission for notifications for some tests, and now I want to ask for notification permission again.

Is that possible?

I’m using the app on Expo app emulator on iOS.

**`Update:` I found a way by uninstalling `Expo` app, then reinstall it back, but it's not practical.

Answer (score 3):

The best option without reinstalling in this case is to access the "Settings" menu in the phone/emulator you are using.
You should have an "Expo" item on which permissions ares shown

Example permissions menu for Expo:

[image: Example permissions menu for Expo]

Comment: How does one get to the settings screen from the Expo app screen in the simulator?

Comment: import { Linking } from 'react-native';

onPress: () => { Linking.openURL('app-settings:') }